# How to iterate through different timeframes?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to create a small simple script where the strategy is to buy if the MACD has crossed positively across all time frames (and to sell if negative all timeframes). However since pinescript does not allow arrays or lists I am not sure how to tell my script to iterate through "1W" "3D" "2D" "1D" "20h"...etc.

Does anyone know of a way I can iterate through multiple timeframes in this language?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you look at the security() function?

Comment: yep, currently my only approach is to hard code it this way: 
'
res="1W"
macd= security(tickerid, res, macdval)
signal=  security(tickerid, res, signalval)

'res2="3D" '
'macd2 = security(tickerid, res2, macdval)'
'signal2=  security(tickerid, res2, signalval)'



was hoping there is a better approach than this

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You need to create separate variables for each timeframe.